# How to build a simple counter with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, model-view-controller

I would like to build a simple counter based on session with Spring MVC which increments by one while I reload the page. Below is the code I tried so far:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("counter")
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home(@ModelAttribute Counter c) {

        System.out.println(c);
        c.setCounter(c.getCounter+1);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("counter", c);
        mv.setViewName("home");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Yet I always get 0..

If I use `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpSession` In spring MVC I get an error while trying to access the session attributes.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest req) {

        if (req.getSession().isNew()) {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("counter", new Integer(1));
        } else {
// java.lang.NullPointerException: null
            int counter = (int) req.getSession().getAttribute("counter");
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
```

Thanks

EDIT: The following code works:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(@CookieValue(value="counter", defaultValue="0") Long counter, HttpServletResponse res) {

    counter++;

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("counter", counter.toString());
    res.addCookie(cookie);

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("messaggio", "hellooo "+counter);
    mv.setViewName("home");
    return mv;
}
```

Comment: Can you add code for view _home_?

Comment: Home is just a empty thymeleaf template. I would like to reload the page and see the counter increments.